# stored procedure and split function.....how to

Tags: sql-server-2008, function, split

I have a stored procedure that saves RS report parameters into a table, the user runs the report with their selection and it is saved for retrieval at a later date. Its all worked great until I had to switch it to multi-selection parameters.

This is because as it is it stores the parameter like -

> Value, Value, Value

. So when it comes to retrieval it only see the string in the table. What I need to get it to do is split the parameters when it is saving them into the table. I've got hold of a function to do this but am struggling to implement it into the stored procedure.

Its a basic stored proc that inserts savename, para1, para2. Hope I've not been too vague!

Answer (score 0):

You can split multiple values like this, `#Table` stores values which you required

```
    CREATE TABLE #Table (Value VARCHAR(MAX))
    DECLARE @Values VARCHAR(MAX) = (select StringStoredValue from TableName)
    SET @Values = 'INSERT INTO #Table SELECT ' + REPLACE(@Values, ',',' UNION SELECT ')
    EXEC(@Values)
    --Here you can do join with #Table and find those values which required
    SELECT * FROM #Table 
    DROP TABLE #Table
```

Comment: OK, I can see how that works, how do i get this working for more than one parameter?? ie. i have 4 columns - One with a Savename and the other 3 have values in??

Comment: What is type of those parameter?

Comment: Now see the answer I edited it, pass TableName which have string value stored in database.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @N  int
Declare @Temp varchar(max)
Declare @Count int

Declare @Tempdata
(
Id int,
Splitval varchar(max)

)
Insert into @Tempdata
select * from [dbo].[split]('@Parameter',',')

set @Count = select * from @Tempdata

set @N=1
while @N<=@Count
begin
set @Temp=select Splitval from @Tempdata

Insert into Tablename(parameter)
values(@Parameter)

@N=@N+1;
end
```